# How to get pair to swap two AttributeError: 'Contract' object has no attribute 'methods' in Web3.py

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I am using python. I am going to get a pair to swap two tokens. How to get it?
I am going to get the reverse value of two tokens. But I can't get this value, I am using method like this.

`

uniswap_pair = uniswap_factory.methods.getPair(tokenIn, tokenOut).call()

uniswap_reserves = uniswap_pair.methods.getReserve().call()

```
reserve0 = uniswap_reserves[0]

reserve1 = uniswap_reserves[1]`
```

But I have errors.

`uniswap_pair = uniswap_factory.methods.getPair(tokenIn, tokenOut).call() AttributeError: 'Contract' object has no attribute 'methods'`

Comment: If it is only a single pair please look up the pair address through Uniswap user interface or on EtherScan.

Comment: In uniswap, when swap two tokens, I am going to get a pair address of two tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Web3.py documentation how to [call smart contracts is here](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#working-with-contracts). What you are writing does not make sense with Python and looks like JavaScript and Web3.js code.

I suggest you start with Web3.py tutorials and basics before trying to tackle more complex problems, because this knowledge is prerequisite for you to program anything useful.

Comment: I am sorry, But I can't get pair using the function getPair(), I am using python. How to get reserve value of pair?